# Local html page \raw\ folder in webview with links to another html page

Tags: android, android-webview

I'm using a WebView to display a html page which is stored in the \raw\ directory so I can easily localize it.
I load the page using

```
 InputStream inputStream = getResources().openRawResource(R.id.htmlPage1);
 StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
 try {
     IOUtils.copy(inputStream, writer);
 } catch (IOException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
 }
 String x = writer.toString();
 WebView w = (WebView) myFragmentView.findViewById(R.id.webView);
 w.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/", x, "text/html", "utf-8", null);
```

which works fine. Images and css files used in the html page are stored in the \assets\ directory.

Now I want to add links to another local page (< a href="htmlPage2.html">Click here< /a>) in my html page. The WebView tries to load the page from assets (which seems to be the correct behavior). Unfortunately the \assets\ folder isn't localized.

How can I link to other local html pages without giving up the feature of localization?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Step #1: Probably use a more distinctive URL pattern for the links to help you distinguish them (e.g., `<a href="/this/is/another/raw/resource/htmlPage2.html">`)

Step #2: Register a `WebViewClient` with your `WebView`

Step #3: In `shouldOverrideUrlLoading()` of your `WebViewClient`, if the URL matches the pattern you use for these links (see Step #1), go through your load-the-resource logic and return `true`, else do nothing and return `false` to pop up a Web browser on that URL