# How can a WebView display a local page through a hyperlink?

Tags: android, hyperlink, android-webview

I am creating help pages for my application that I display in a WebView. I can easily see the home page, but I can't figure out how to follow local hyperlinks.

Here is my code so far:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  ...
  content = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.content);
  content.loadData(getTextFromResource(R.raw.help_main), "text/html", "utf-8");
  content.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
      view.loadUrl(url);
      return true;
    }
  });
}

private String getTextFromResource(int aResourceId) {
  InputStream vRaw = getResources().openRawResource(aResourceId);
  ByteArrayOutputStream vStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
  try {
    int i = vRaw.read();
    while (i != -1) {
      vStream.write(i);
      i = vRaw.read();
    }
    vRaw.close();
  } catch (IOException e) {
  }
  return vStream.toString();
}
```

And in `/res/raw/help_main.html`:

```
<h1>Help menu</h1>
<ul>
  <li><a href="help_overview.html">Overview</a></li>
  ...
</ul>
```

The link never leads to the Overview page, I tried with these URLs but nothing worked:

- help_overview.html
- ./help_overview.html
- file://res/raw/help_overview.html
- file://android_asset/help_overview.html
- file://android_res/raw/help_overview.html

Links to the internet work, but not local links, what URL should I use?

I've seen the question [Local html page \raw\ folder in webview with links to another html page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14548286/local-html-page-raw-folder-in-webview-with-links-to-another-html-page), but its answer doesn't say *what* URL I should provide.

Answer (score 0):

```
webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
```

Comment: That is one short and useless answer :-(.

Comment: No it's not. I tried your version first and it didn't work. I tried his and it worked.