# HTML link to local file in WebView with target API 24

Tags: android, android-webview

How can one use HTML links to navigate to local files (HTML pages) in `WebView` if targeting API 24 or higher?

This has been discussed before and solutions use the `file://` URI scheme.
What worked so far was using

```
<a href="file:///android_asset/my_page.html">Go to local page</a>
```

in an HTML file that is displayed in a `WebView` and clicking the link would load the local page `app/src/main/assets/my_page.html`.

However, starting from API 24, a [FileUriExposedException](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/FileUriExposedException.html) is raised when clicking such a link. From logcat:

```
mypackage.myapp W/System.err: android.os.FileUriExposedException: file:///android_asset/my_page.html exposed beyond app through Intent.getData()
...
mypackage.myapp W/System.err:     at org.chromium.android_webview.ResourcesContextWrapperFactory$WebViewContextWrapper.startActivity(ResourcesContextWrapperFactory.java:121)
mypackage.myapp W/System.err:     at org.chromium.android_webview.AwContentsClient.sendBrowsingIntent(AwContentsClient.java:203)
```

According to the documentation, this is thrown when "an application exposes a `file://` Uri to another app.". I wonder why this is the case, because according to the log everything seems to happen inside `mypackage.myapp`.

The documentation suggests using the `content://` URI scheme instead, but this does not work in HTML files.

Answer (score 4):

The following workaround (based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14549079/905686)) intercepts the loading of a `file://` URI in the `WebView` and then loads it directly by app code with `WebView.loadUrl(...)`. This is possible by overriding `WebView.shouldOverrideUrlLoading` in a `WebViewClient` passed to the `WebView`, e.g. when initializing it.

As there was an API change for this method in API 24, for compatibility there are two versions in the code (technically in the API<24 case one could also do as before, letting `WebView` open the `file://` URI because the exception is not raised on devices running API<24).

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 24) {
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView webView, WebResourceRequest webResourceRequest) {
            if (webResourceRequest.getUrl().getScheme().equals("file")) {
                webView.loadUrl(webResourceRequest.getUrl().toString());
            } else {
                // If the URI is not pointing to a local file, open with an ACTION_VIEW Intent
                webView.getContext().startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, webResourceRequest.getUrl()));
            }
            return true; // in both cases we handle the link manually
        }
    });
} else {
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView webView, String url) {
            if (Uri.parse(url).getScheme().equals("file")) {
                webView.loadUrl(url);
            } else {
                // If the URI is not pointing to a local file, open with an ACTION_VIEW Intent
                webView.getContext().startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url)));
            }
            return true; // in both cases we handle the link manually
        }
    });
}
```

The reason why there is an exception when letting the `WebView` open the link must have something to do with the `Intent` created by the `WebView` but I don't see whether or how it is exposed to another app.

That the workaround works is then because the `WebView` does not do anything with the link (no `Intent` is created), instead, when the link is clicked, the app gets control and opens the `file://` URI direclty by passing it to `WebView.loadUrl(...)` - which seems to be fine.

I assume (but do not claim) that regarding security this is fine because the URI is only used to load the file it points to in this single `WebView` (and if this was problematic the system should throw the `FileUriExposedException`).

Comment: You save my day, you are great!

Answer (score 0):

I never link in the HTML that way if you need to load an other page:

```
<a href="file:///android_asset/my_page.html">Go to local page</a>
```

I link this way because my map struture look like [this](https://ibb.co/dGGxSv):

```
<a href="my_page.html">Go to local page</a>
```

You just need that methode in your MainActivity.java and that will work:

```
private class MyBrowser extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        if (url.startsWith("tel:") || url.startsWith("sms:") || url.startsWith("smsto:") || url.startsWith("mailto:") || url.startsWith("mms:") || url.startsWith("mmsto:") || url.startsWith("market:")) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        }
        else {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

If you have any questions or It still don't work let me know