# How to reference local files using hyperlinks in html files on Android 10?

Tags: android, html, google-chrome, firefox, hyperlink

I've created two html files named "file1.html" and "file2.html" in the same directory on my Android 10 based smartphone. file1.html contains the following hyperlink:

```
<a href="file2.html">Relative link to file 2</a>
```

But when I open file1.html in browser and click the link I face the "File note found" message.
On older Android versions it worked fine.

Replacing the link with the absolute:

```
<a href="/storage/emulated/0/Documents/file2.html">Absolute link to file 2</a>
```

helps for Firefox browser, but still fails for others (Chrome, Opera, Dolphin, etc.).

Any ideas how to overcome the issue at least for Chrome and Opera?

Comment: Does this answer your question. https://stackoverflow.com/a/44984353/13685592

Comment: I'm not an expert in Java and Android, but seems that here the same problem is solved for WebView (which is responsible for displaying web pages inside an app), not for an arbitrary web browser.

Answer (score 0):

use the **file://** protocol to link to the files:

```
<a href="file:///storage/emulated/0/Documents/file2.html">Absolute link to file 2</a>
```

also make sure the application has the permission `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`